# What are the scoping rules for options set on the background layer (with the backgrounds package)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

As illustrated by the pictures below, some options appear not to be constrained by their scope (e.g., line thickness and dashing) while others do. (Using the `backgrounds` package.) What is the rule?  Separately, note the odd consequences for the arrowhead size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
\draw[ultra thick,blue] (0,1) -- (2,1);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw (0,2) -- (2,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer={ultra thick,red,dashed,->,>=latex}]
\draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
\draw[ultra thick,blue] (0,1) -- (2,1);
\begin{scope}[on background layer={red,dashed,ultra thick}]
\draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer={->,>=latex}]
\draw (0,2) -- (2,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: questionOfScope]

Comment: but u changed the options for the second `tikzpicture` by not adding `ultra thick, dashed,`  -- after adding the options see the difference

Comment: @jsbibra That's the whole point. It exposes the scoping differences of the options.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
        \draw[ultra thick,blue] (0,1) -- (2,1);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \draw (0,2) -- (2,0);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[on background layer={ultra thick,red,dashed,->,>=latex}]
            \draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
        \draw[ultra thick,blue] (0,1) -- (2,1);
        \begin{scope}[on background layer={red,dashed,ultra thick}]
            \draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[on background layer={ultra thick,dashed,->,>=latex}]
            \draw (0,2) -- (2,0);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```